# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Non Critical Path Stage

Tags: jenkins

I have a declarative pipeline and I'd like to be able to mark some steps as essentially not being on the critical path. Taking the below simplified example, I would like Job B and Job C to be part of the overall process, but I don't want job D to be dependent on them, and allow failures to be handled without failing the rest of the pipeline. Job A takes the most time, and running B and C at this time minimizes the overall length the process runs for.

Being explicit, nothing should depend on B and C, but I want them to run as part of Stage 1.  Job D should depend on Job A. Essentially I would like the pipeline to run Jobs B and C and then not care about them once they are kicked off

```
 pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1 Name') {
      parallel{
        stage('Stage 1 parallel A'){
          steps {
            build 'Job A'
          }
        }
        stage('Stage 1 parallel B') {
          steps {
            build 'Job B'
          }
        }
        stage('Stage 1 parallel C') {
          steps {
            build 'Job C'
          }
        }
      }
    }  
    stage('Stage 2') {
      steps {
        build 'Job D'
      }
    }
    stage('Stage 3 Name') {
      parallel{
        stage('Stage 3 parallel A'){
          steps {
            build 'Job F'
          }
        }
        stage('Stage 3 parallel B') {
          steps {
            build 'Job E'
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: The dependencies between the jobs are not fully clear to me, does D depend on A? Do B and C depend on A?

Comment: Edited initial post with more clarity, but ideally nothing should depend on B and C, but I want them to run as part of Stage 1. Job D should depend on Job A. Essentially I would like the pipeline to run Jobs B and C and then not care about them once they are kicked off

Comment: Have you considered `build job: "Job X", wait: false`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that syntax, it doesn't look like a declarative pipeline. I didn't find anything  here either https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: `build` is a step, not a pipeline construct, check here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job. `build job: "Job X"` is an alternative syntax for `build "Job X"`. Or, less confusing, `build(job: "Job X")`, `build(job: "Job X", wait: false)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `wait: false` for the `build` step?

> `wait : boolean` (optional)
>
> If true, the pipeline will wait for the result of the build step before jumping to the next step. Defaults to true.
>
> -- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1 Name') {
      parallel{
        stage('Stage 1 parallel A'){
          steps {
            build 'Job A'
          }
        }
        stage('Stage 1 parallel B') {
          steps {
            build(job: 'Job B', wait: false)
          }
        }
        stage('Stage 1 parallel C') {
          steps {
            build(job: 'Job C', wait: false)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // ...
```